# What are the available NFT standards?

Tags: anchor, nft

I'm looking to ditch Metaplex NFT standard for something simpler. What I'm looking for:

- Compatible with Token2022
- Smaller accounts and less CPIs
- Live on mainnet right now

I know that [Shadow](https://github.com/GenesysGo/shadow-nft-standard) is working on something but it still feels very early, lacks a lot of tooling and makes me fall into dependency hell.

Are there any other NFT standard that fit these criteria?

Answer (score 3):

The closest I could find was [NFToken](https://nftoken.so/docs/overview) by the team at Glow Wallet. It checks 2/3 of the boxes, being a leaner standard and live on mainnet. However from my research it is not compatible with Token22.

EDIT: [@CloakdDev](https://twitter.com/CloakdDev/status/1660910965611806720) had something cooking up a few months ago but unsure of the progress. Noticed you commented on it, but this may still be an option if it's continuing to be worked on.

Answer (score 3):

It's currently bleeding edge (read: doesn't have docs and not deployed to networks), but token-2022 integrates the spl-token-metadata interface.

More information about the interface at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/tree/master/token-metadata/interface

The token-2022 implementation lives at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/master/token/program-2022/src/extension/token_metadata/processor.rs

An earlier version of the interface is described in this forum post: https://forum.solana.com/t/srfc-00017-token-metadata-interface/283